# Virtual PC 2007 USB floppy disk drive support

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-virtual-pc

On my copy of Windows Vista I downloaded Virtual PC 2007. And I was wondering, does Virtual PC 2007 support a USB floppy drive? I don’t have my hands on a OS, but when I insert a disk with my USB FDD in non-OS mode (The BIOS) and I am already aware of the Virtual PC 2007 USB support doesn’t exist, but I know it’s just reading it as a normal floppy disk drive, because I get the classic “Non system disk or disk error.” But before spending money on a operating system, is it compatible?

All you people with USB floppy drives and Windows Vista SP1 or higher and Windows XP SP3, test!

PS : Why are USB FDD's obsolete? Is it cause they are slow?

Comment: I believe that you sir, are the only owner of a USB floppy drive left on the planet. Congrats on being so esoteric. The only thing that device is good for is getting data off your floppies. Once you do that, take those files and create an ISO. Mount that ISO in Virtual PC as a CD and you should be fine. Just make sure you have made a bootable ISO which is compatible with the OS installer.

Comment: or make em imgs and mount them as a virtual floppy. I'd also add virtualpc is *really* old, and you might want to consider virtualbox or something else more modern.

Comment: **I really have 2 USB floppy disk drives ;)** But anyway, how DO I mount them as ISO's, and if so, can I just burn 1 ISO with all my files on it to a physical CD? I think I probably can, just burn it to a CD! But anyways, how do I mount it as a iso?